# How to find scanner device in /dev folder in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, device

When I do `lsusb`, I get:

> Bus 020 Device 013: ID 03f0:7d04 Hewlett Packard Deskjet F2100 series  Serial: CN76R3R53Q04TK

How can I associate it to a file in `/dev`?

Comment: If you are trying to scan from the command-line on OSX, using `libusb`/`sane`, please ask another question and notify me and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you're trying to do low-level USB hacking of the printer, just use libusb, libusbp, or IOKit.  If you're trying to print to the printer, ask on https://superuser.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Actually I am running a docker container with ubuntu 14.04 image on osx host, and want to access scanner device inside docker container. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a file-like handler to a USB device is job of a *kernel driver*.

In general, however, printers don't *need* a kernel driver. They usually just do bulk USB transfers, which you handle with libusb, and that works without an explicit `/dev/` entry describing exactly your printer.

Depending on your OS, libusb's communication with the USB stack of your kernel will look different (and I'm not overly versed with OS X), but there's probably something like a `/dev/bus/usb/20/0/13` or so; really depends.

Anyway, unless you want to write a CUPS printer filter, you probably don't want to interfere directly with the USB device, but let your printing system do that.

So, TL;DR: That's a printer. It usually does not have a `/dev/` entry on its own. Use libusb to communicate with USB devices on a USB packet level.